# evince is showing errors in error messages in the terminal

Tags: evince

I have installed ubuntu 12.04.
There are two users accounts in my system.
evince showing problem in one of my user accounts (user5).

```
(evince:26724): EggSMClient-WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported

(evince:26724): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to read the recently used resources file at `/opt/home/user5/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but the parser failed: Failed to open file '/opt/home/user5/.local/share/recently-used.xbel': Permission denied.

(evince:26724): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to store changes into `/opt/home/user5/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Failed to create file '/opt/home/user5/.local/share/recently-used.xbel.6OQ9NX': Permission denied

(evince:26724): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to set the permissions of `/opt/home/user5/.local/share/recently-used.xbel', but failed: Permission denied
```

The above mentioned error keep on repeating.
I have given permission for recently-used.xbel file, but the problem persists.

Please help to fix this issue?

Comment: The root cause are `permission denied` errors, but why the hell is `/home` beneath `/opt`?

Answer (score 3):

It could be [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingApparmor):

Check `/var/log/kern.log` for entries like :

`May 11 10:17:35 dev kernel: [2336998.770824] type=1400 audit(1431364655.819:726): apparmor="DENIED" operation="chmod" parent=19487 profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/data/home/fritz/.local/share/recently-used.xbel" pid=23290 comm="evince" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1001 ouid=1001`

check where your `home` directory is.  If it's a symlink from `/data/home -> /home` then you need to modify AppArmor to to have the true home directory in it.

`sudo vim /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home`

and modify `HOMEDIRS` accordingly

`@{HOMEDIRS}=/home/ /data/home/`

then restart apparmor

`sudo /etc/init.d/apparmor restart`

Comment: Hi. I'm not the author but this helped me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the message "Gtk-WARNING" to access:

```
/home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel # user is echo $USER
```

or

```
/root/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel # if exist
```

It is solved like this:

First verify the permissions

```
ls -l /home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
-rw------- 1 user user 3321 nov 21 08:58 /home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel

sudo lsattr /home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
--------------e--- /home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

If the result is not described above. For example:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 3321 nov 21 08:58 /home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
-----i--------e--- /home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

Fix it like this:

```
sudo chattr -i /home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
sudo chown user:user /home/user/.local/share/recently-used.xbel
```

Note: For security reasons it is better to remove it

Source: Post [Gtk-WARNING](https://www.maravento.com/2018/11/gtk-warning.html)